# Lookahead in Regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to extract venue from a file which contains several articles using regex. I know that the venue starts with either For/From and is followed by date which starts with a day of the week or author's name if the date is missing, I wrote the following regex to match the venue, however it always matches everything till the author's name which means the date also comes in the venue if that article has a date.

```
"""((?<=\n)(?:(?:\bFrom\b)|(?:\bFor\b)).*?(?=(?:(?:Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)|(?:[A-Z]+))))""".r
```

Why is my code not matching the days if it is encountered but rather goes ahead to match [A-Z] which is the author's name.

Input: "The Consequences of Hostilities Between the States

From the New York Packet.

Tuesday, November 20, 1787.

HAMILTON

To the People of the State of New York:"

The line "Tuesday, November 20, 1787." is optional and may not occur in all articles. I want the output to be "From the New York Packet."
I am getting the correct output for articles that do not have a date, however I am getting the output "From the New York Packet.

Tuesday, November 20, 1787." for articles that contain the date.

Comment: Please simplify to `(?<=\n)(?:From\b)|For\b).*?(?=Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday|[A-Z]+)`

Comment: So the author name is characterized as "at least one uppercase letter"?

Comment: Authors name is all capital on the next line if the date is missing else it is followed by the date

Comment: For example , look at this "The Consequences of Hostilities Between the States

From the New York Packet.

Tuesday, November 20, 1787.



HAMILTON



To the People of the State of New York:" I need to extract "From the New York Packet."

Comment: Then you maybe should use `\n[A-Z]+\b` to match the authors name?

Comment: Author's name is matching for me but I want the venue to end at Packet. but it also extracts the date in the venue which means it does not match Tuesday

Comment: Hint for next time: Include a sample of the text you want captured. This saves a lot of explaining.

Comment: Please specify the tool you are using (C#, javascript, Perl, etc) and provide samples of what you do and don't want to match.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, all you really need is

```
^(From|For).*
```

with the multiline flag.

---

> I know that the venue starts with either For/From
>
> and is followed by date which starts with a day of the week or author's name if the date is missing
>
> it always matches everything till the author's name which means the date also comes in the venue if that article has a date.

Sounds like you want to find an entire line within a text file that begins with "From" or "For"

```
^(From|For)
```

*(Set the multiline flag on so that `^` matches the beginning of a line rather than the beginning of input).*

is followed by an optional date

```
\s+(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)?
```

followed by the author's name

```
\s+\w+\s+\w+
```

followed by everything until the end of the line

```
.*
```

**Unless, of course** you mean that you want to skip the date and match only the For/From and the author's name (not the date). That cannot be done in Regex alone - you can use grouping to extract the desired values, though.

Comment: No I dont want the date I want everything starting from From/For and  upto the date (check my question edit)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the answer here because JDB provided too much information, but based on what you've said here, I think he's ALMOST correct, he's just misunderstood what you wanted to capture.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to capture the entire line that starts with For or From, so you can simply use this:

```
^(For|From).*$
```

The ^ and $ anchor the match to the start and end of the line, and the .* matches everything inbetween.

Here, [try it out](https://regex101.com/r/XBJBbM/1) with whatever examples you like.

If this needs to be more complicated, I'll update my answer.